# How can I merge HTML attributes with component data in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to extract some repeated code into a Vue component. I want to be able to pass a list of CSS classes into the component using the `class` HTML attribute, and merge those with a "default class" that is defined in the component. I want the public interface of this component to resemble a standard HTML element, but if I try to use "class" as a prop Vue throws an error about using a JS keyword. If I try to use $attrs, my default class gets wiped out.

Is it possible to merge HTML attributes with local component data, and use the result in my template? Below is what I would like to achieve:

```
<template>
  <img src="imageUrl" class="classes"
</template>

export default {
  computed: {
    imageUrl() { return 'urlString' },
  },
  classes() { return `${this.$attrs.class} default-class` }
}
```

And I'd expect an implementer to be able to use my component like so:

```
<CustomImageComponent class="class-name another-class" />
```

Which I'd expect to render this:

```
<img src="urlString" class="class-name another-class default-class" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question 100%, but it looks to me like you're looking for `class="my-static-class" :class="my-passed-classes"`. which combines static and variables in class name

Comment: That's what I'm after, but I want to use HTML attributes rather than a custom prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It already happens (automatically)

using `<CustomImageComponent class="class-name another-class" />`

will render`<template><img src="imageUrl" class="my-default-class"/></template>`

as `<img src="imageUrl" class="my-default-class class-name another-class"/>`

(in that order, with the in-template class first, and the passed classes after)

the issue is that if you have a **nested** DOM element that you want to apply it to, you cannot do that and you will have to use a prop

ie:

using `<CustomImageComponent class="class-name another-class" />`

will render`<template><div><img src="imageUrl" class="my-default-class"/></div></template>`

as `<div class="class-name another-class"><img src="imageUrl" class="my-default-class"/></div>`

and there's nothing you can do about that, other than use custom props.

Comment: No idea why this wasn't working for me... I must've had a syntax error or something, but tried again and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `v-bind:` or only `colon(:)` before the attributes to pass data as a value and that's it, Vue automatically merge classes, see link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/30oly1z326

Answer (score -1):

A couple things you could do, both with `this.$el.classList`.

On mounted:

```
mounted() {
    this.$el.classList.add('default-class');
}
```

Computed property:

```
computed: {
    classListWithDefault() { 
        return `${this.$el.classList.toString()} default-class`;
    }
}
```